# Generating dynamic forms from Excel xlsx to HTML and JavaScript

Tags: java, xml, excel, web-applications

I am trying to create dynamic forms for a web application using Excel spreadsheets.

The form has some relatively advanced rules like the following:

- Field A > Field B.
- Field C must be shown if Check Box D is checked.
- Field E is read-only and must be a sum of A and B.
- Field G is sum of E and A or F and A if B is empty.
- Combinations of rules.

These are just examples of some of them.

The server is implemented and runs in Java which I guess narrows the possible solutions. My first thought is to parse the excel spreadsheet with all required information into XML to enable either serverside or clientside conversion. This is basicly because I have found tools that work on either side.

So my question is whether anyone knows of a tool that can perform this conversion or if anyone knows of a better solution?

I have looked at https://github.com/davidmoten/xsd-forms but I am not sure it can implement all the required rules and license information is sparse.

I realize this question is quite vague but so is the task. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Apache's POI API for reading Excel sheet and JAX-B for generating XML from the data read from excel sheet.

You can read the more details about reading excel files using Apache's POI API over [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. These do seem like viable options but I am looking for a tool to especially do the JAX-B part to cut down on development time if such a tool exists.
At the moment I'm looking at converting the Excel spreadsheet to XForms and using [EMC XForms Engine](https://community.emc.com/docs/DOC-4345) to accomplish a conversion to HTML + JavaScript.